# WCF How to enable metadata?

Tags: c#, wcf, metadata

I am trying to get my svc file working under IIS. In my project, when I press F5 I got the svc working. So I know everything is okay, right? Except for IIS.

I am working on a Windows XP Pro machine and in IIS I've added a virtual directory.

Here's my code:
IcarePlanActions (project: A)

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICarePlanActions
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<string> GetAllClients();
    }
}
```

Client: (project: A)

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary
{
    public class Client : ICarePlanActions
    {
        public List<string> GetAllClients()
        {
            List<string> clients = new List<string>();
            clients.Add("Hendrik de Jong");
            clients.Add("Miep de Berg");
            clients.Add("Jaap Jongeneel");
            clients.Add("Joop Prakman");
            clients.Add("Pieter Schaakman");

            return clients;

        }
    }
}
```

Web.config (project: B)

```
  <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="CarePlanService.Service1Behavior"
          name="WcfServiceLibrary.Client">
          <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.ICarePlanActions">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="CarePlanService.Service1Behavior">
            <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

CarePlan.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfServiceLibrary.Client" %>
```

When I run this service (which is on IIS) with wfctestclient I get this error

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://localhost/CarePlanService/CarePlan.svc
>   If this is a Windows (R) Communication
>   Foundation service to which you have
>   access,  please check that you have
>   enabled metadata publishing at the
>   specified address.

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**

I didn't get the service working under IIS. First I manually create a virtual directory and pointed to the directiry where the svc is located. This didn't work. I don't know why.

Then I went to Visual Studio and changed the server setting (Right mouse on the project, properties, tab Web, click `Use local IIS Web Server` and click `Create Virtual Directory`. When I did this, it worked under IIS with the code above.

Comment: Edited title - this has nothing to do with the C# programming language.

Comment: I've not used WCF like this but should you put your service implementation inside the datacontract? and if so, there's no datamember defined in the contract. Just looks weird to me. But i've never hosted in IIS...

Comment: @Martijn: really silly question: when you're trying to connect using the WcfTestClient, is the web site up? If you do the changes proposed here (drop the [DataContract], use "mexHttpBinding" for the mex endpoint), I have no trouble getting the metadata at all. But you have to do a "View in Browser" on the *.svc file first, in order to launch the built-in web server - and then you can connect to the URL with your WcfTestClient

Comment: @Marc: I've done the changes as proposed below. I want to host the service on the local IIS. When I do a "View in Browser" the service is hosted by Visual Studio, right?

Comment: @Martijn: the service is hosted by the integrated web server, Cassini, yes - the point is: it needs to be "up and running" before you can access it. Either by means of an IIS virtual directory that's defined, or by starting it up in Cassini.

Comment: The pooint was that it didn't run under IIS. I got it working now. I've edited my startpost with the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLUTION

I didn't get the service working under IIS. First I manually create a virtual directory and pointed to the directiry where the svc is located. This didn't work. I don't know why.

Then I went to Visual Studio and changed the server setting (Right mouse on the project, properties, tab Web, click Use local IIS Web Server and click Create Virtual Directory. When I did this, it worked under IIS with the code above.

Comment: this worked for me, so which means it works in IIS server but not in Visual Studio development server. you know why?

Answer (score 8):

First, remove the [DataContract] attribute in Client.

Then, recompile and make sure that you have the WcfServiceLibrary.dll in the /bin directory for your virtual directory.

Your config should use this endpoint for metadataexchange:

```
<endpoint address="mex" 
    binding="mexHttpBinding" 
    contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Comment: I've changed my files, but I still don't get it working. I've modified my startpost with the changes.

Answer (score 2):

You reference the data contract as the implementation of the service. That's invalid.

```
[DataContract]
public class Client : ICarePlanActions
{

<service behaviorConfiguration="CarePlanService.Service1Behavior"
      name="WcfServiceLibrary.Client">
```

Change this to reference the implementation of your service! What does the implementation of your service look like?

Maybe you should just remove the DataContract attribute from the Client class. Also this is not your "Client", it is the implementation of the service.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `"\%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -i`
2. Remove Virtual Directory and create it again.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the service name in `Service.svc` file

```
<ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="SvcCalculator.**Calculator**"
           CodeBehind="**Calculator.svc.cs**" %>
```

Hope it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your service **namespace**, and service **class** names correspond to the **App.config** file.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
   <service name="WcfCustomLibrary.Service1">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
   </service>
  </services>
 </system.serviceModel>


namespace WcfCustomLibrary
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
public class Service1 : IService1
{
```